# SELECT FBA IF QTY > 0 ELSE use FBM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to output stock to load to the Amazon Inventory Loader. IF I have FBA stock then the row should be FBA if however there is no FBA stock the row should be FBM.

**FBA and FBM are the two stock location values from the StockLocation.Location Table.**

```
[sku], [product-id], [price], [fulfillment-center-id], [quantity]
[AAA], [0001], [0.10], [AMAZON_EU], [10]
[AAA], [0001], [0.10], [DEFAULT], [1]
[BBB], [000], [0.10], [AMAZON_EU], [0]
[BBB], [000], [0.10], [DEFAULT], [1]
```

So Based on the above the Result will look like this;

```
[sku], [product-id], [price], [fulfillment-center-id], [quantity]
[AAA], [0001], [0.10], [AMAZON_EU], [10]
[BBB], [000], [0.10], [DEFAULT], [1]
```

This is what I have so far;

```
DECLARE @source nvarchar(255) = 'Amazon'
DECLARE @subSource nvarchar(255) = 'Store1'
DECLARE @FBM nvarchar(255) = 'DEFAULT'
DECLARE @FBA nvarchar(255) = 'AMAZON_EU'
SELECT    T1.ItemNumber AS [sku],
  T1.BarcodeNumber AS [product-id],
  T3.SalePrice AS [price],
  T5.Location AS [fulfillment-center-id],
  T4.Quantity AS [quantity]
FROM [stockitem] T1
INNER JOIN StockItem_Titles T2 on T1.pkStockItemID = T2.fkStockItemId
INNER JOIN StockItem_Pricing T3 on T1.pkStockItemID = T3.fkStockItemId AND T2.Source =     T3.Source AND T2.SubSource = T2.SubSource
INNER JOIN StockLevel T4 on T1.pkStockItemID = T4.fkStockItemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockLocation T5 on T4.fkStockLocationId = T5.pkStockLocationId
WHERE T3.Source = @source AND T3.SubSource = @subSource
```

As it is this will output two rows for each sku, so I need to reduce that to either FBA OR FBM

*If it helps the database is LINNWORKS.*

Thank you in advance for your help and direction

Stu

[image: LinnWorks Database Structure]

Comment: From where to find whether FBA stock is available or not? can u explain a bit more

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have come up with, if you have another or indeed a better or correct way then PLEASE do post it.  I used MIN to get the FBA over the FBM alphabetically, not sure it is the best approach, but it looks to work.

```
DECLARE @source nvarchar(255) = 'Amazon'
DECLARE @subSource nvarchar(255) = 'Store1'
DECLARE @FBA nvarchar(255) = 'AMAZON_EU'
DECLARE @FBM nvarchar(255) = 'Default'

SELECT  T1.ItemNumber AS [sku],
    T1.BarcodeNumber AS [product-id],
    'EAN' AS [product-id-type],
    T3.SalePrice AS [price],
    '' AS [minimum-seller-allowed-price],
    '' AS [maximum-seller-allowed-price],
    'New' AS [item-condition],
    CASE 
        WHEN T5.Location = @FBA THEN NULL
        ELSE T4.Quantity
    END AS [quantity],
    CASE
        WHEN Quantity <= 0 THEN 'x'
        ELSE 'a'
    END AS [add-delete],
    6 AS [will-ship-internationally],
    3 AS [expedited-shipping],
    'Message' AS [item-note],
    MIN(T5.Location) AS [fulfillment-center-id],
    CASE 
        WHEN T5.Location = @FBA THEN 'AMAZON_EU'
        ELSE 'Default'
    END AS [fulfillment-center-id]

FROM [stockitem] T1
INNER JOIN StockItem_Titles T2 on T1.pkStockItemID = T2.fkStockItemId
INNER JOIN StockItem_Pricing T3 on T1.pkStockItemID = T3.fkStockItemId AND T2.Source =     T3.Source AND T2.SubSource = T2.SubSource
INNER JOIN StockLevel T4 on T1.pkStockItemID = T4.fkStockItemId AND T4.Quantity <> 0
LEFT JOIN StockLocation T5 on T4.fkStockLocationId = T5.pkStockLocationId
WHERE   T3.Source = @source AND T3.SubSource = @subSource AND LEN(T1.BarcodeNumber) > 5
GROUP BY T1.ItemNumber, T1.BarcodeNumber, T3.SalePrice, T4.Quantity, T5.Location
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect AND T2.SubSource = T2.SubSource is wrong or not required
Pulling conditions up into the join can sometimes help the query optimizer

```
DECLARE @source nvarchar(255) = 'Amazon'
DECLARE @subSource nvarchar(255) = 'Store1'
DECLARE @FBA nvarchar(255) = 'AMAZON_EU'
DECLARE @FBM nvarchar(255) = 'Default'

SELECT T1.ItemNumber AS [sku],
       T1.BarcodeNumber AS [product-id],
       'EAN' AS [product-id-type],
       T3.SalePrice AS [price],
       '' AS [minimum-seller-allowed-price],
       '' AS [maximum-seller-allowed-price],
       'New' AS [item-condition],
       CASE 
          WHEN T5.Location = @FBA THEN NULL
          ELSE T4.Quantity
       END AS [quantity],
       CASE
          WHEN Quantity <= 0 THEN 'x'
          ELSE 'a'
       END AS [add-delete],
       6 AS [will-ship-internationally],
       3 AS [expedited-shipping],
       'Message' AS [item-note],
       MIN(T5.Location) AS [fulfillment-center-id],
       CASE 
          WHEN T5.Location = @FBA THEN 'AMAZON_EU'
          ELSE 'Default'
       END AS [fulfillment-center-id]

 FROM [stockitem] T1
 JOIN StockItem_Titles T2 
   on T1.pkStockItemID = T2.fkStockItemId
  AND LEN(T1.BarcodeNumber) > 5
 JOIN StockItem_Pricing T3 
   on T1.pkStockItemID = T3.fkStockItemId 
  AND T2.Source = T3.Source 
  AND T2.SubSource = T2.SubSource
  and T3.Source = @source 
  AND T3.SubSource = @subSource
 JOIN StockLevel T4 
   on T1.pkStockItemID = T4.fkStockItemId 
  AND T4.Quantity <> 0
 left JOIN StockLocation T5 
   on T4.fkStockLocationId = T5.pkStockLocationId    
GROUP BY T1.ItemNumber, T1.BarcodeNumber, T3.SalePrice, T4.Quantity, T5.Location
```